# Running and testing Visual Studio extensions (workflow)

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

What is the workflow when developing VSIX extension? Should I uninstall and install extension each time I rebuild the project, or is there any easier way to do this?

Is it possible somehow to rebuild it and see the changes without uninstalling it and installing again?

Comment: In fact, with Visual Studio 2017, it redeploys everything each time you run/debug (CTRL+F5 or F5), so you don't have to do that manually, it's automatic

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks I'll try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Add the solution:***

Like Simon Mourier's suggestion, for the VSIX project, you don't have to uninstall it if you want to update it. It would cover the previous project automatically during you run the latest version.